# Looking for a simple wireless headset with microphone

Tags: wireless, audio, headphones, headset, microphones

After trying multiple headsets, earphones, and any other shape of wireless audio device, with issues each time, I realized I have two choices:

1. To spend another $40,000 dollars in the hope of finding the one perfect headset.
2. Get a decent recommendation from someone who already owns one.

So here I am. My requirements are, I would have thought, simple. But surprisingly rare in practice:

1. Wireless. Duh. Should connect to a PC, so USB dongle or base station is okay.
2. Has a microphone. On the headset, not the dongle/base station.
3. Sounds better than a radio.
4. Sounds better than a radio while using the microphone. Seems like a "duh", but this pretty much rules out all Bluetooth-based devices, except those using proprietary technology like FastStream.
5. No white noise or buzzing when the audio output is silent. I don't constantly have sound playing, and I don't want to have to take my headset on and off depending on my sound usage at the moment. This tends to rule out many RF-based ones, which seem to have mild white noise when the audio is silent.
6. No auto-off. This rules out pretty much all European ones, since EU regulations require broadcast stations to turn off after 5 minutes of silence. But like I said above, I don't listen non-stop, and I don't want to hack an inaudible sound just to prevent my headset from shutting off.
7. Can listen while charging. I don't always remember to charge my headset, and the last thing I want is a forced 15 minute break from my computer, because the headset automatically turns off as soon as it's connected via USB (Why is this even a thing!?)
8. Reasonably durable. Should last at least several months before breaking. Again, I too would have thought this was obvious, but *cough* Creative *cough* Logitech *cough*.
9. Both ear pieces can produce audio at the same volume out of the box. I mean, I don't see how that would be a "feature", but my recently owned Creative Outlier Sports couldn't produce half the volume with the right ear piece as the left, so...

I'm not particular about the shape, but if it's in-ear, I'd rather drivers that are less than 5mm, so they actually fit in the ear canal. If over-ear, I'd prefer material that doesn't gradually disintegrate, leaving pieces of itself everywhere.

Unfortunately, most of the "features" I'm looking for don't appear in technical specs, and some of them are hard to find even in user reviews. I'm tired of gambling (and losing), so I'd really appreciate if someone can confirm owning a headset that satisfies all of the above.

Comment: It's the main reason why I use an external microphone (Blue Snowball)....almost no wireless PC headset I've tested has acceptable levels of white noise. Most are made for gaming and don't care about absolute audio quality.

Comment: The Arctis 7 came close to fitting the bill. Wireless, decent quality microphone, auto-off can be disabled, works while charging, and pretty good audio quality. The fact that it bricked after less than a month of use kind of ruins the experience, though. So, something like that but that lasts more than a few weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using the Logitech G933 for almost a year now, and it's been answering my requirements.

1. Wireless, with a USB dongle that's as small as many bluetooth dongles (Less than 2 inches).
2. Detachable microphone on the headset, as well as a button to turn the microphone on and off. The microphone's connection to the headset seems like a standard 3.5mm, but I haven't tested replacing it. One flaw is that it has a "flexible" handle that seems to keep going back to the straight position, no matter how many times I try to bend it towards my mouth. It's hearing range is quite tight, so putting it near my mouth is a must to be heard clearly.
3. Excellent sound quality, as far as my ears can tell. Can use it to play games, listen to music, watch videos, and not feel anything off.
4. Same as 3. The microphone has no effect on the sound quality, and is actually at a semi-decent quality itself.
5. Sound quality is crisp, even at a long distance. At worst, I had mild sound cut-offs while on a different floor from the dongle, but no noise.
6. Unfortunately, it does have auto-off if silent for a while. But it doesn't lose sync with the dongle, and there's a physical on-off button on the headphone itself, so it takes only a second to turn it back on. It's better to be charging it rather than wearing it when not listening to anything, anyway.
7. I've very rarely encountered running out of battery, but the USB-C charging port can be used while listening, with no issues, other than the cable getting in my face. The port is only for charging, so you can just as easily connect it to a computer or a wall socket USB charger. The charging port is on the left ear, which may or may not matter depending on whether the nearest USB port is on your left or right. Using a magnetic USB-C charging cable (bought separately) makes the process of setting the headphones for charging, and picking them up, extremely smooth and fast, as well.
8. The pieces of plastic that hold the earphones extension mechanism are not durable enough to hold the weight of the earphones. Depending on how you hold the headphones they may break. However, since it's just a piece of plastic, they can be easily reinforced with duck-tape or rubber band, or anything else that's slightly more durable, and the problem is solved. The important thing is that the electronics are durable, and even with the plastic piece breaking, the headphones continue to work perfectly fine. Also, only that small plastic piece broke, while everything else, like band or ear cushioning, isn't showing even mild signs of wear. So, despite being a fragile Logitech product, it's been holding up reasonably well.
9. Haven't noticed any issues with the volume balance.